# NotifyAll not working properly: program to control thread execution order - print integers sequentially

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

First of all, this is not a homework.
I have written a piece of code so that:

Thread-1 prints 1,4,7,... (diff is 3)

Thread-2 prints 2,5,8,...

Thread-3 prints 3,6,9,...

And the final output should be:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...

Here's the code that works wonderfully well:

```
package threadAlgo;

public class ControlOrder {
    volatile Monitor monitor = new Monitor();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ControlOrder order = new ControlOrder();

        Thread one = new Thread(new Task(order.monitor, 1));
        one.setName("Thread-1");
        Thread two = new Thread(new Task(order.monitor, 2));
        two.setName("Thread-2");
        Thread three = new Thread(new Task(order.monitor, 3));
        three.setName("Thread-3");

        one.start();
        two.start();
        three.start();
    }
}

class Monitor {
    int threadNumber = 1;
}

class Task implements Runnable {

    private Monitor monitor;
    private int myThreadNumber;
    private int currentCount;

    Task(Monitor monitor, int myThreadNumber) {
        this.monitor = monitor;
        this.myThreadNumber = myThreadNumber;
        this.currentCount = myThreadNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            while (monitor.threadNumber != myThreadNumber) {
                synchronized (monitor) {
                    try {
                        monitor.wait(100); //DOESN'T WORK WITHOUT THE TIMEOUT!!!
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            synchronized (monitor) {
                if (monitor.threadNumber == myThreadNumber) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + currentCount);
                    currentCount = currentCount + 3;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (myThreadNumber == 3) {
                    monitor.threadNumber = 1;
                } else {
                    monitor.threadNumber = myThreadNumber + 1;
                }
                monitor.notifyAll();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The only problem is that if I use wait() instead of wait(timeout), then the thread halts.

**UPDATE:**

Wait condition (while loop) should be inside synchronized block. A lesson for beginners, including me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always

- perform notifyAll/notify in conjunction with a change in state.
- check the state change before using wait() in a loop.

If you call notify() and no wait() is waiting, then the signal is lost, so unless you check a state change, (or timeout) you can block forever waiting for a signal which doesn't change.